# Gráfico multindex pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Olá,

Tenho o seguinte dataframe:
Onde tenho um período de 3 anos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria de estar plotando um gráfico do VALOR agupado por mês e ano, eu fiz da seguinte forma, mas não deu certo.

```
df.groupby(['MES','ANO','VALOR']).sum().plot()
```

onde estou errando?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qual o resultado que você deseja? A ordem de agregação altera o resultado final:

```
df.groupby(['ANO','MES'])['VALOR'].sum().plot(kind='line')
```

Comment: ah sim, deu certo, obrigado. Agora cai em um outro problema, que seria na geração do gráfico.
queria plotar no eixo Y a coluna VALOR e no Eixo X as colunas [ano e mes] ordenadas, porém não ficou da forma que eu queria, eu teria que criar um novo tópico para ajuda?